# which XML write/parse/modify is good for android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to parse and modify the XML in android ..Can any one suggest which XML parser is better to parse and modify the XML in android ..?

Currently I'm using XMLpullparser but using this i'm not able to modify the XML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath is available for Android developers I believe. I use that all the time for any XML parsing really.

Answer (score 2):

If the XML has a simple structure then you can deserialize the file into an object. You modify some properties of that object and serialize it to XML afterwards.

**XStream** is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again. It can be found [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

I think this is a clean way, but it isn't the easiest way if the XML file is very complex (because you have to map its structure to a Java class).

Answer (score 0):

XMLPullParser isn't really designed for complex tasks AFAIK. SAX Parser is much better for advanced tasks, but it's also not as easy to use.

For manipulating XMLs, you could use SAX Filters. Look at this tutorial (IBM tutorials are great!): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipsaxfilter/